# Ошибка в парсере на node.js

Tags: node.js

На текущий момент мы имеем проблему...

Node.js скрипт, запускает сервер и ждет клиентов, на запрос клиента парсит сразу несколько сайтов (от 4) и отдает в ответ отсортированные результаты...

При нагрузке от 50 обращенй в секунду, через 5-10 секунд после запуска начинают зависать все внешние соединения к сайтам которые нужно парсить, соединения обрываются по таймауту (получаем Error: socket hang up), но это ничего не дает любые новые так же зависают...

Пробовали запуск на разных серверах в разных дц, проблема в самом скрипте...

FreeBSD: 9.2
Node.js: 0.10.22

Тестовый скрипт - https://www.alphabid.com/parser2.js

Comment: я надеюсь вы в курсе что `async!=fork` ? в том смысле что

    var _async = require('async');
    function a(cb) {
    var c=0;
    for (var i=0;i<100000000;i++) {
            c=i*2;
    }
    console.log("A end");
    cb(null,c);
    }
    
    function b(cb) {
            console.log("B end");
            cb(null,"BBB");
    }
    
    _async.parallel([a,b],function(err,results) {
            console.log(err,results);
    });

выведет:

    A end
    B end
    null [ 199999998, 'BBB' ]

Comment: но по мне всё хорошо выглядит, скорее всего вас притормаживают поставщики данных, возьмите свой "сервер", который тупо будет отдавать данные без всяких ограничений (можно статику) и попробуйте нагрузить, скорее всего таких тормозов не будет.

Comment: вот я простеньким скриптом проверил одного из ваших поставщиков:

    time curl http://megayachts.ru/news >/dev/null;for ((a=0;a<500;a++));do echo $(echo -n "$a ";curl -v http://megayachts.ru/news &> $a.log && echo OK) & done


    $ grep 'left intact' * |wc -l
    413

это значит, что 413 соединений из 500 они отбросили. так-то. *tip: кэшируйте данные, не переспрашивайте аплинка по каждому чиху - мы не в XXIV веке живем*

Comment: megayachts.ru это случайный сайт

вот пример реальной xml
http://xml.intecppc.com/feed.php?aid=2000253&said=100&ip=66.55.44.33&q=viagra&ref=http://qwerty.com/&ua=Chrome&n=

смысл в том, что кешировать нельзя

Comment: необходимо получать всегда свежие данные...

Comment: попробуйте парсер выполнять паралельно, чтобы он не лочил основной поток, т.к. в запросах все выглядит нормально 

https://github.com/rvagg/node-worker-farm